# Error using Math.pow and Math.sqrt in Java

Tags: java, math

I cannot really figure out what my errors are in the code below. Also: My code looks so unelegant, any advice how to structure it better?

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.Math;

public class FlightSimulator {
public static void main(String[] args){

    int time;
    int v_y;
    int v;
    int v_squart;
    int height;


    Scanner myscan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Please enter the time for which you want to output the height of the " +
            "plane ");
    time = myscan.nextInt();
    if(time==0){
    System.out.print("The height of the plane is 456 meters over ground."); 

    }
    else{
        v_y = 51 - time*3;
        v = Math.pow(v_y+20, 2);
        v_squart = Math.sqrt(v);
        height = 456 - v;
        System.out.print("The height of the plane is" + height);

    }
}
}
```

Comment: So... what are the error messages? At least you're trying to assign doubles to ints.

Comment: Why are you calculation of the square root of the square of a number?

Comment: you need to cast or using `Math.rint`, you can't assing a double to an int

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
v_y = 51 - time*3;
v = (int)Math.pow(v_y+20, 2);
v_squart = (int)Math.sqrt(v); // why take the square root of something you just squared...
height = 456 - v;
System.out.print("The height of the plane is" + height);
```

Integers cannot contain decimal values, Math.pow and Math.sqrt both return `double` types. You have declared `v_y`, `v` and `v_squart` as `int` types and you have to convert the operations to integers. You could also declare your variables as `double` types

```
int time;
double v_y;
double v;
double v_squart;
double height;
```